# Group by with unrelated counts

Tags: t-sql, group-by

I have three tables, one, two and three.

## one

[image: table one contents]

## two

[image: table two contents]

## three

[image: table three contents]

With this query

```
select one.id, count(two.id) as num_twos, count(three.id) as num_threes from one
left join two on one.id = two.one_id
left join three on one.id = three.one_id
group by one.id
```

I expect to get

```
1 2 1
2 1 4
3 0 0
4 0 0
```

because there are

- two records in two that relates to one_id 1 and one record in three that relates to one_id 1.
- one record in two that relates to one_id 2 and four records in three that relates to one_id 2.

but I get

[image: result]

Why? The counts seems to get multiplied. Can I get the desired behavior without subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image this :

```
select one_id,count(id) as num_Twos
from Two
group by one_id
```

with the output :

```
one_id      num_Twos
1           2
2           1
```

And then join to the main table (this way, the main records, from table One, are not duplicated,and no need of distinct ):

```
select
    id, num_Twos, isnull(num_Twos,0) as numTwos
from One 
    left join
    (
        select one_id,count(id) as num_Twos
        from Two
        group by one_id
    )as two
        ON id =two.one_id
```

output: (used isnull - to put 0 instead of NULL)

```
id          num_Twos    numTwos
1           2           2
2           1           1
3           NULL        0
4           NULL        0
```

the same thing , with table 3

From comments: this way, you don't need the top level group by , because the all the information are already aggregated in the `() as Two` and `() as Three`

or with distinct:

```
select one.id
        , count(distinct two.id) as num_twos
        , count(distinct three.id) as num_threes 
from one
left join two on one.id = two.one_id
left join three on one.id = three.one_id
group by one.id
```

output :

```
id          num_twos    num_threes
1           2           1
2           1           4
3           0           0
4           0           0
```

the source:

```
with One 
as (select 1 id union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4)
,Two 
as (select 1 as id, 1 as one_id Union all select 2,1 union all select 3,2)
,Three
as (select 1 as id,1 as one_id union all select 2,2 union all select 3,2 union all select 4,2 union all select 5,2)
```

also , you can rewrite it as :

```
select id
        , isnull(num_twos,0) as num_twos
        , isnull(num_threes,0) as num_threes
from one
left join (select one_id ,count(id) as num_twos from two group by one_id) as two on one.id = two.one_id
left join (select one_id ,count(id) as num_threes from three group by one_id) as three on one.id = three.one_id
```

Comment: Distinct worked, but I fail to see why and if it is safe to always use it. (I always stay away from unions).

Comment: It seems like adding distinct solved the problem already, but I must understand why and if it can fail.

Comment: @AndersLindén,  I like the second option, with count inside  and then join it , see the updated answer

Comment: It must be right, thanks for the suggestion, I tick this answer.

Comment: @AndersLindén: The first join duplicates each `one` row where it's matched more than once by `two`. The second join potentially duplicates each `one` row again, in the same manner. Try your query without the `group by` (and without aggregation, of course) to see the underlying row set. Also trying commenting out either or both joins to see what effect each of them has on the resulting set. That should give you the necessary insight.

Comment: It seems to get more complicated if I want to use sum instead of count however. Maybe I am not set with this solution.

Comment: Your elegant answer seems to invalidate the use of group by on top level.

Comment: @AndersLindén - yes, that 's the idea, no need of the top level group by, because in this way you don't have to group/count - all the information are already aggregated in the `() as Two` and `() as Three`

Comment: No more endless group by lists!